# GMSGeocoder stopped returning full address

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, reverse-geocoding

A few days ago, whenever I try to reverse geocode from a coordinate using GMSGeocoder, I stopped receiving a fully detailed response containing the street name and/or house number. Now, I only receive the city and country, and sometimes the postal code.

As this happened to anyone? Is there a reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: This just started happening to me as well. I don't have a reason, but am continuing to look into it.

Comment: You need to post your code

Comment: This issue has cleared up for us. I believe it was just an issue with Google's APIs. Will update if something changes

Comment: Yes, Google fixed this issue today! Looks like they had a bug in GMSDecoder, only affecting iOs Google maps SDK. More information here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78809393